# Can windows.print() be executed without without user intervention?

Tags: printing, sapui5

I currently have a 'Print' Button which executes the following code.

However, how in some circumstances, the user would like to go directly to the print. However, if they're on a mobile device, wouldn't the content be altered to fit BEFORE the print is executed.

in other words, is there a way to get a full-screen layout print from a mobile device.

```
var wind = window.open("", "Print");

            var sContent = this.getView().byId("idStackedChart").exportToSVGString({ // read content and fit with page size
                width: 800,
                height: 300
            });

            var sContent = this.getView().byId("idStackedChart").exportToSVGString({ // read content and fit with page size
                width: 800,
                height: 300
            });

            var sContent2 = this.getView().byId("idStackedChart2").exportToSVGString({ // read content and fit with page size
                width: 800,
                height: 300
            });

            var sContent3 = this.getView().byId("idStackedChart3").exportToSVGString({ // read content and fit with page size
                width: 800,
                height: 300
            });

            wind.document.write(sContent);
            wind.document.write(sContent2);
            wind.document.write(sContent3);
            wind.focus();
            wind.print();
            wind.close();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by ".. the user would like to go directly to the print.."?

Comment: Sure. I've seen a few tutorials using tcpdf etc, but they all feature an on click event. I need the pdf download as soon as the user enters the app.

Comment: Alright. Although that sounds unusual, you can try putting this code into the `onAfterRendering` method of the controller.js and see if it is executed.

Comment: Great I'll try that thank you@

Comment: Also. Is there any way the force the PDF to NOT be responsive? E.g. when viewed from a mobile device the html will respond but I want the PDF to show all contents.

Comment: Sorry but that's out of my UI5 expertise. I'll post it here if I find out.